# Encrypting PDF with Itext produces blank file

Tags: file, encryption, itext

I am using Itext 5.0.6 and when attempting to encrypt a pdf, I get zero size ( blank file) as a result. Any idea ? If I don't try to encrypt, then I get the file okay.

```
try
{
    File f = new File("C://secure_abc.pdf");
    FileOutputStream out = new FileOutputStream(f);
    PdfReader reader = new PdfReader("C://abc.pdf");
    System.out.println("reader.getFileLength(): "+reader.getFileLength());
    PdfStamper stamp = new PdfStamper(reader, out);
    stamp.setEncryption(null, null,
    PdfWriter.ALLOW_PRINTING, PdfWriter.ENCRYPTION_AES_128);
}
```

Comment: You forget to close `stamp`.

Comment: actually I close it after encrypting but same result.. I have also updated to itext 5.5

Comment: It was the bouncy castle lib that I was missing. No where in the release notes Itext tells that there is a dependency, should have used maven version.. Seems to be working Thanks a lot for your help

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Make sure to use bouncy castle libraries, iText has dependencies on the lib.

Comment: You should accept your own answer. Note that I'm surprised that you don't get any exceptions when BouncyCastle isn't present. I would have expected a `ClassNotFoundException` which would immediately have informed you (and us) what was wrong with your code.

Answer (score 0):

Please add the following line at the very end:

```
stamp.close();
```

You created a zero-length file when you do this:

```
FileOutputStream out = new FileOutputStream(f);
```

But no bytes are written to that output stream up until you close the `PdfStamper` instance.

Also: 5.0.6 is quite old. Why not use a more recent version?

Comment: actually I close it after encrypting but same result,I have also updated to itext 5.5 , still getting blank file